# Why do the original values of a DbEntityEntry match the new values?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to implement auditing in my MVC 4 with EF application as per this post http://jmdority.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/using-entity-framework-4-1-dbcontext-change-tracking-for-audit-logging/.

I am having trouble finding the changed properties when an entity is modified. I have a class that inherits from DbContext and overrides the SaveChanges method. In this new SaveChanges method I have the following code to look for changed properties, where entity is from ChangeTracker.Entities().

```
foreach (var propertyName in entity.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
{
    var originalValue = entity.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName);
    var newValue = entity.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName);

    if (!object.Equals(originalValue, newValue))
    {
        // Insert an auditing record.
    }
}
```

This issue is that the originalValue is always equal to the newValue, even though nothing has been saved to the database yet. How can I get the original value so I can check if the property has changed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your client code (that actually changes the property value), your full `SaveChanges()` code may help as well.

Comment: You may need to make a call to `context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges` before inspecting the changes ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is this line of code:

`DbSet.Attach(...)`

The summary of this function (from `System.Data.Entity.IDbSet`) is: "Attaches the given entity to the context underlying the set. That is, the entity is placed into the context in the Unchanged state, just as if it had been read from the database."

Comment: Could you be more specific on how this actually helps in obtaining the changes on the entity?

Comment: Some where before you check changes there is call of DbSet.Attach(entity) which clear all changes

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this:

```
foreach (var propertyName in entity.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
            {
                String originalValue = "";
                String newValue = "";

                originalValue = entity.GetDatabaseValues().GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString();

                newValue = entity.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString();

                changes += propertyName.ToString() + " : " + originalValue + " --> " + newValue + "\n";
            }
```